# SpringMVC PUT request to edit data but instead, got a new one

Tags: spring-mvc, post, thymeleaf, httprequest, put

I'm practicing Spring/Thymeleaf and facing an issue
I create a a PUT request to edit but instead it act as POST by create a new data

Here are my codes
**Controller**

```
// imports



    @Autowired
    private UniversityService universityService;

    // More codes


    @PutMapping("/universities/{id}/edit")
    public String editUniversity(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("thisUniversity") University updatedUniversity,
            BindingResult result,
            @PathVariable Long id) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "editUniversity";
        }
        universityService.updateUniversity(updatedUniversity);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

**Service**

```
// imports

@Service
public class UniversityService {

    @Autowired
    private UniversityRepo universityRepo;

//    Add a university
    public University createUniversity (University newUniversity) {
        return universityRepo.save(newUniversity);
    }


// More codes


    public University updateUniversity(University updatedUniversity) {
        return universityRepo.save(updatedUniversity);
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<1-- head -->
  <form th:taction="@{'/universities/'+${thisUniversity.universityId}+'/edit'}" th:object="${thisUniversity}" th:method="POST">
      <!--  The below tag is required for PUT/DELETE request  -->
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">

    // HTML elements

    <input type="submit" value="Save University">
  </form>
```

I also have `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` in application.properties file

I have try `th:method="PUT"` in form tag or not including `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">`
But the results are still the same

Comment: Stop using entities in your api. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: Has your updatedUniversity entity a proper id set?

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the id as a path variable but not giving it to the updated object, which is why it gets saved to a new object instead of editing the existing one.